# Why does the Misal rico de Cisneros uses the word "Qiſſa", and what is it supposed to mean? Why not "Miſſa" (Missa)?

Tags: medieval-latin, abbreviations, font

The *Misal rico de Cisneros*, produced by archbishop Cisneros, the archbishop of Toledo, Spain, in the early sixteenth century, is a Latin Catholic missal also known as the *[Missale secundum consuetudinem almae ecclesiae Toletanae](http://bdh.bne.es/bnesearch/detalle/bdh0000012826)*.

I've been making it into a font. I want to make the font highly useful to medievalists, and plan to implement any MUFI ligature and codepoint found in the missal.

[image]

One question I have that I've not been able to find in any guide of medieval Latin scribal abbreviation is why the missal uses the word «Qiſſa» («Qissa») in its table of contents…

[image: miisal]

It can be seen in the third line on the first page. Why the *Q*? It seems *M* is what is meant.

Comment: What amazing handwriting! *Missa* is even written *Adissa* a few times on the second page. I look forward to the experts’ comments.

Comment: The amount of variants of *M* in *Missa* is quite perplexing! I counted eight, but I might have missed something. Do the titles look the same in the book or is this variation only found in the table of contents?

Comment: @MartinKochanski When you see a question you like, please remember to vote up!

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta It seems like all the capitals have many variants, `S` has at least five, and `D` at least 3; `E` at least six. I'm not sure they have any meaning beyond decorative, but what's perplexing to me is the use of a Q where an M seems like it ought to go; and since it's done often it can't be a mistake.

Comment: @FredrickBrennan It seems pretty clear to me that this is an "M" that looks like a "Q," not a "Q." (Consider the "M" in "Missa Generalis" about halfway down the first page: it's definitely between a "Q" and an "M.") So, I don't think the right question is, "Why does the author write 'Qissa.'"

Comment: *Supremely irrelevant comment:* The bowed **M** is sometimes offered as an explanation for D+ (D reversed) for 'mille:'

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I agree with brianpck's comment: I don't understand why you're reading this glyph as a Q. In isolation, it might look like a Q, but considering the context, it appears to be a variant of M (it's not that unusual I think for capital M to have a closed bottom in certain handwriting styles).

Have you ever seen this glyph used for Q in this text? The symbol I see used for Q is different. See page 62, which has Quotiens spelled like this:

[image]

Quid, page 64:

[image]

Several words, page 10:

[image]

Only the left side of these Qs looks the same as the capital M used in Missa. The tail of the Q is straight rather than curling up.

There are other variants for capital M, but that seems to be a common situation in this text. I also see multiple variants for lowercase d (one with a vertical ascender, as in the words *munditia* and *repellendas,* and one that curves, as in *defensione* and *deuota*).

The variant of capital P with a pointy top that is used on the fourth-to-bottom line of the first page in your picture also seems relevant, as it's another example of a rounded stroke being used interchangeably with a pointy-topped stroke.