# What do three diagonal dots above a letter mean in the "Misal rico de Cisneros" (Spain, 1518)?

Tags: medieval-latin, abbreviations

I can't seem to find this in any books about medieval scribal abbreviations.

Manuscript: http://bdh-rd.bne.es/viewer.vm?id=12826&page=246

page 223/1613
[image: 2]
[image: 1]

They can be found all throughout the manuscript. As stated in [my other question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/11066/why-does-the-misal-rico-de-cisneros-uses-the-word-qi%C5%BF%C5%BFa-and-what-is-it-suppos), I've been making the manuscript into a font, so want to know if there's a MUFI codepoint for these three diagonal dots & what they mean.

Comment: The dots are being used in three ways; abbreviations; footnote links (as at the bottom of p242); punctuation. The triple dots in the lower example,  question marks, are (N.B.) each in a group of four "What did you go out to see; A reed shaken by the wind ? But what did you go out to see ? A man in soft clothing ?"

Answer (score 9):

These triple dots appear to be serving two separate purposes.

1. **The passive -ur ending:** In your first image, the word intended is *perficient**ur***, and the same triple dot is used on page 224 for *cognoscent**ur***.
2. **An interrogative sign:** The first triple dot in your first image, and the succession of triple dots in your second, all seem to indicate that the preceding is a question:

   > Et unde hoc michi: ut veniat mater domini mei ad me?

   And your second image:

   > Quid existis in desertum videre? Arundinem vento agitatam? Sed quid existis videre? Hominem mollibus vestitum?

I have only limited experience with paleography, but I've not seen triple dots used in this way before.

Comment: Is it that the question-mark dots are besides the preceding letter, and the -ur dots are above it?

Comment: @Rafael The Q. dots are *next* to the letter only to make room for the Full-stop/Period placed below them.