# What does a red v with a dot above mean in the Misal rico de Cisneros (Spain, 1518)?

Tags: medieval-latin, abbreviations

What do the red `v.` mean?

Manuscript:
http://bdh-rd.bne.es/viewer.vm?id=12826&page=246 page 675

As stated in [my other question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/11066/why-does-the-misal-rico-de-cisneros-uses-the-word-qi%C5%BF%C5%BFa-and-what-is-it-suppos), I've been making the manuscript into a font.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the "Versicle" character, Unicode 2123, "Versiculus", ℣ if your screen can display it.

It is also possible that you may come across the "Response" character, U+211F, "Responsum", ℟, although this is much more common in the Liturgy of the Hours than in the Mass. (You will note that you have the word on your sample page, only slightly abbreviated).

Comment: Thank you so much! Indeed, the manuscript does include ℟...I just mistook it for a capital rum rotunda due to ignorance. Now I'll be sure to label it correctly.

Comment: It’s a great adventure you’re undertaking and I hope you will find some way of letting us see the result when you get to the end of it.

Comment: This is what I've got so far :-) https://imgur.com/MOHN7Tp